# Open/copy file in use vb6

Tags: vb6, io

I have a .txt file that is constantly in use (locked) by process. How would I read from this file from another vb6 program? I tried copying it first and then reading, but FileCopy gives:

> Runt-time error '70'  Permission denied

and so does opening file with `Open "file.txt" for binary as...`

Comment: Is it possible that an other instance have access to this file?

Comment: Another process (.exe file) which is always running has a constant access to this file. But not another instance of my vb6 app.

Comment: Try copying file using Copy or Xcopy from command prompt and not from VB copy Command. you can easily call a batch file using shell command to do it.

Comment: THey both output Sharing violation...

Comment: You could change both programs to open the file with appropriate sharing or more limited locking.

Comment: if I had control over the other one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible if another process has locked the file with no share permission. One way to do it would be to use low level APIs of Shadow Copies. But as far as I know, those are undocumented. Although sysinternals does provide some examples. (no source code)